# React Draggable stopping onClick for Child component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, draggable, css-transforms

I am trying to create draggable cards that can also flip over on click.

This is my card

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './Card.scss'

function Card() {
  const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)

  return (
      <div className={`card ${flip ? "flip" : ""}`}>
        <div className="front" onClick={()=>{setFlip(!flip)}}>
          <h1>Front</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="back" onClick={()=>{setFlip(!flip)}}>
          <h1>Back</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

This is the Draggable wrapper for the Card

```
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
import Card from './Card'

function DraggableCard() {
  return (
    <Draggable>
      <div>
        <Card />
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  )
}

export default DraggableCard
```

This is the CSS that is supposed to trigger onClick for the Card to flip

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0deg))
    translate(var(--translate-y, 0))
    rotate(var(--rotate, 0deg));
  transition: transform 0.7s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 14, 14);
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card.flip {
  --rotate-y: -180deg;
}
```

The onClick handler in the Card should change the useState for "flip" and then, in turn, alter the className from "card" to "card flip" this should then trigger the CSS to flip the card. I can see that the className is not changing on click.

I saw that the Draggable README talked about using

> Use an intermediate wrapper `(<Draggable><span>...</span></Draggable>)` in this case.

I added the extra `<div>` around the Card component in DraggableCard, but it did not seem to change the outcome. Did I miss understanding the README from react-draggable?

I assume that it is being overridden by the Draggable component but am struggling to figure out how not to let this happen.